# After implementing Google Analytics according to documentation, I am getting an Use Of Unresolved Identifier 'GGLContext' Error

Tags: swift, google-analytics, xcode6

I have implemented the Google Mobile Analytics according to steps outlined on the [Google Documentation Page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift).  I have added the pod, I have the bridging header in place, I have downloaded the configuration file and imported the plist file provided.  However, when I insert the following code into my `appDelegate` file, I get the error `Use of Unresolved Identifier 'GGLContext'`.

```
        // Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
    var configureError:NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

    // Optional: configure GAI options.
    var gai = GAI.sharedInstance()
    gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true  // report uncaught exceptions
    gai.logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose  // remove before app release
```

I have searched many forums and cannot find any solution.  I have even run `pod try Google` and looked at their example project and cannot see a difference.  Has any experienced this before (XCode 6.4, OSX 10.10.5, Swift 1)?

Answer (score 9):

Don't use CGLContext try to implement it manually with your Google Analytic ID.

I find this more reliable, as I also try to do it the Google documented way that didn't work for me as well, I believe they have to update their context (I believe this is due to swift 2 - *Update*).

**Example:** enter this in your **AppDelegate.swift** within **`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`** method.

```
// Init GAI.
let Tracker = GAI.sharedInstance()

//Add Publisher Track ID
Tracker.trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXXXXXXX-X")
```

Please ask if you have any other question you would like to manually implement (`trackUncaughtExceptions`, `logger` etc)

## **UPDATE:**

Your bridge header file should look something as following, you should add whichever feat you're using in Google Analytic Framework.

```
//Google Analytics
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAITracker.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
```

#### **Here is a screenshot of available classes.**

[image]

Comment: I just get a different error `Use of unresolved identifier 'GAI'`.  

I must be missing something.  One thing I notice is that after creating the bridging header file, even though I check my application target during creation, when I look in File Inspector, under my `Target Membership`, both options are de-selected.

Comment: What `.h` your including in your header file?

Comment: #import <Google/Analytics.h>

Comment: U need to add `GAI.h` don't use `Google/Analytics.h` please see my answer reference to this matter

Comment: The app is in the app store (without Google Analytics) but if I get a chance to try this I will.  Unfortunate that Google's own documentation doesn't include this.

Comment: @Craig.Pearce yes, iOS development will be 10x faster when people stop depending on broken/undocumented Google libraries

Answer (score 4):

just do this

pod 'Google/Analytics'

and

pod install

create -Bridging-Header.h in your project root.

and then copy that to .h file

```
  #import <Google/Analytics.h>
```

and drag and drop GoogleService-Info.pist to root of project.

this is so important. go to **build setting** and find **swift compiler-code Generation** and then set  $(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h to **Objective-C Bridging Header**

clean project and build and then run.

Comment: Check sample app @ https://github.com/phanisai4u/sampleAppsSwift/tree/master/GoogleAnalyticsSampleSwift

Answer (score 2):

At the point in time the 'Google/Analytics' pod doesn't support Bitcode, so when you go to do a production build, you will run into problems. Especially if you want to support WatchOS or tvOS.

At this point in time, using the "GoogleAnalytics" pod seems to be the best option, and setting up the tracker manually with

```
// Init GAI.
let Tracker = GAI.sharedInstance()

//Add Publisher Track ID
Tracker.trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXXXXXXX-X")
```

You can also go to https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=671 and scroll to the bottom to vote for Google to fix the recommended path to work with Bitcode.

Answer (score 1):

To import 'Google/Analytics' framework to your swift code, simply import the module using `.` as package separator:

```
import Google.Analytics
```

It will import all required classes without having to modify the bridging header.

Answer (score -1):

You can manually import the GGLCore.framework in ViewController.swift like

```
import GGLCore
```

Like this you can manually import the GGL file